# Validating a single text box against two different rules with jQuery Validation skips the second error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Consider the following HTML:

```
<form id="frm">
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />
    <input type="submit" value="click me" />
</form>
```

I need to validate the text box against 2 different rules using jQuery Validation Plugin v1.13.1 and jQuery 1.7.2 and hence:

```
$(function(){
    var validator = $('#frm').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            element.attr('title', error.text());
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod('rule1', function (value, element) {
        return value != null && value.length;
    }, 'Rule 1 failed!');

    $.validator.addMethod('rule2', function (value, element) {
        return false;
    }, 'Rule 2 failed!');

    //Assign both rules to the text box.
    $('#txt').rules('add', { rule1: true, rule2: true });

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        if(!validator.form()) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

- Click the above button (leave the text box intact).
- Hover the text box, it says that the Rule1 has failed.
- Now, enter something in the text box so that Rule1 validates correctly.
- Press the button again.
- Hover the text box again. Although the Rule1 has been successfully validated, however, it still says Rule1 failed, instead of Rule2.

The question is why? Here's the associated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dp5pLr8x/).
Thank you.

Comment: The problem has something to do with the way you're placing the error in the title. It works fine if you remove that bit.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to set the text box's title attribute to the error message that's happening. I do not want to add a new element to the DOM. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, jQuery validation tries to read the error message from the element's `title` attribute if it is present. Of course, since you're *setting* the error message in the title, this becomes permanent. This odd behavior [is apparently deprecated](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignoretitle) now and will soon be gone.

In the meantime, however, the fix is to use the `ignoreTitle` option when creating your validator:

```
var validator = $('#frm').validate({
    ignoreTitle: true,
    ...
}
```

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dp5pLr8x/4/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think the problem you are running into is value.length does not return null/T/F, it returns a range from 0-whatever so Rule 1 will never validate.

Try (value.length > 0) for T/F.

Comment: No, that's not the case. (value != null && value.length) basically means (value != null && value.length > 0).